# How can we use xor operation on integers in z3 using python?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

```
from z3 import *
x = Int('x') #declaration
y = Int('y') #declaration
solve((x ^ y)==2) #solving
```

i was unable to perform xor operation in z3 using python.please help tell what is the correct way of writing if i am doing it wrong else suggest some other way of doing it.please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Had to look it up: http://z3.codeplex.com/

Comment: I don't know z3, but I can tell you that there are infinite many pairs of x, y such that x^2 == 2. Won't that pose a problem?

Comment: @Kay: I don't know z3 either, but apparently not. It would happily solve it, saying that x=0 and y=2 was the solution. Which of course is correct. In z3 there would be just 2^n solutions though, where n is the declared length of the BitVec. But, but that's details. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `^` on integers in Python:

```
>>> 2^3
1
```

However, z3 does not use integers, but their own Int objects, and they don't support xor. You have to use the `BitVec` type.

```
x = BitVec('x', 32)
y = BitVec('y', 32)

solve(x^y==2, show=True)
```